# Реализация поля на Unity, для клеточного автомата

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне сказали написать клеточный автомат на Unity, на курсовую.

**Предисловие**

Я понимаю что намного легче было бы реализовать его не через него, но на тему были ограничения "Выбор из предоставляемых преподавателем платформ и языков" и по итогу все разобрали и мне достался Unity С#. Это так к слову, почему именно на Unity

**Основная часть**

Концепцию я придумал и теоретически знаю как реализовать взаимодействия между клетками, но единственное что пока что заставляет встать в ступор, это как реализовать само поле из клеток. Я понимаю что можно наверное что-то придумать, но я никогда глубока не касался Unity и не совсем понимаю с чего начать.

И еще буду очень признателен если поможете советами или примерами реализации такого проекта

Answer (score 1):

Ну если собираешься реализовывать клеточный автомат квадратиками, как все, а не текстурами, то делать поле клеток это бред, поскольку квадратик, это всего лишь пиксель. Из пикселей состоит текстура, не только в `Unity3D`, а ваще везде. Текстуры можно создавать и редактировать [Texture2D.SetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html). Настройки отображения текстуры находятся в `Sprite`, который так-же можно создавать самому [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html). Спрайты отображаются компонентами `SpriteRenderer` на сцене или `Image` на `Canvas`. В отличие от `GameObject`, которые привязаны к сцене, `Texture` и `Sprite`, которые так-же являются `UnityEngine.Object`, нужно `Destroy()` самостоятельно, иначе они так и будут висеть в памяти. Создавать новую `Texture` и `Sprite` каждый раз разумеется не нужно. Либо можно написать шейдер на `HLSL`.